# live action in jQuery for all changes on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a universal function for jquery to detect any changes on the site in model DOM?
For example i have few function in jQuery - with click, submit, mouseover etc. Is possible to detect these all?

```
$(document).?CHECKALL?(function(){
  alert('detected change!');
})
```

Is this possible with javascript and jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("detected change!");
});
```

Depending on what you do with this event, this is going to slow down the browser. Be careful with such a function!

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated as of 1.7.

Comment: whops, copied the code from an older project and didn't realize it still uses `.bind()`. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.on()` handler which takes the place of the `.bind()` handler as of 1.7.

`.on()` can detect a variety of things.

Comment: And how does this answer the question. This is more of a comment to @Alex's answer

Comment: @Starx I answered before Alex did.  Alex also originally put `.bind()` as his answer, not `.on()` which is not correct as of 1.7 and I corrected that .. Read the comments of each answer given before you decide to criticize, please.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend, but this does not answer the question and is still is more of a comment to Alex's answer. Which he indeed changed after you commented. What I didn't know was you answered before him, and so I would like to apologise for tha

Comment: actually i answered 6 seconds before you. but nevermind ;) thanks again correcting `.bind()`.